# Performing certificate authentication using golang

Tags: go, certificate, smartcard

I tried to implement below link for smart card authentication from what I understood that smart card have private key and we can’t extract it. But can we simulate similar authentication method that happens via login
I am able to retrieve public key but how do I complete chain for successful authentication for net/http

Currently i am performing operations via Invoke web request using thumbprint in powershell

[Go: HTTPS Request using a Client Certificate stored on a SmartCard (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889542/go-https-request-using-a-client-certificate-stored-on-a-smartcard-windows/76492274#76492274)